# SimpleDateFormat.parse not detecting incorrect date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Been experimenting with SimpleDateFormat. One thing I do not understand : why does the following returns `ok` ?

```
String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

String input = "2023/03/22";
Date d = null;

try {
    d = format.parse(input);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("nok");
}

System.out.println("ok");
```

Date returned  is absurd too : `Fri Jul 03 00:00:00 CET 190`

Any explanation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Update your knowledge with `java.time` please. `Date` is kind of depreciated now.

Comment: @AxelH I would but the project I'm gonna work on is a fun legacy one. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's spell it out for those readers who want it all in the answer:

**format.setLenient(false) is what you need.**

Here's how you might do it.  I agree with AxelH: You should be using JDK8, `java.time` package and `LocalTime`:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class DateFormatTest {

    @Test(expected = ParseException.class)
    public void testSetLenient_IncorrectDateInput() throws ParseException {
        // setup
        String input = "2023/03/22";
        String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        format.setLenient(false);
        // exercise and assert
        format.parse(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really.  It's a JUnit test that demonstrates exactly what the user wants.  You don't use JUnit?

Comment: I do (but not everyone do ...), but I would mention that the formatter provide a method `setLenient(boolean)` that will do the trick. This require other knowledge that everyone doesn't necessarily have so it would be easier with just one line of explanation ;)

Comment: I gave the explanation in one line in the comment.  Now I've offered some code to prove that I'm right.  Bonus: show how to use JUnit.  I can't imagine why this was voted down by anybody.

Comment: Well, I am the one, did that when it was a code only answer, now I am just waiting you include the comment in your answer. I was told more than once that comments are not a place for answers, everything need to be in the answer. That all

Comment: I understand that, but that's not stopping me to propose improvements when I believe this could be needed, don't see that as an insult.

Comment: No need to fight ! :) Thanks for the response. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

> Any explanation is greatly appreciated!

here we go:
the explanation is simple:

this format **"MM/dd/yyyy"** is pretty simple about how is what, the object is expecting a month day year information to be parsed.

so you are giving this **"2023/03/22"**, then the 1st this is wrong here is that the moth (which should be between 1 and 12) is holding the value 2023, this is interpreted by the parser as the month 12 + 2011 extra months after that.

day 03 is ok, and year 22 means exactly that, the year 22 After Christos birth.

so your resulting date is

the valid data plus the weird offset, i.e.

12/03/0022 +  2011 months.

now 2011 months is the same as: 167 years and 7 months
so we do the math:

12 03 of the year 22 plus 167 years and 7 months... then you get

**Fri Jul 03 00:00:00 CET 190**

---

the solution:

```
format.setLenient(boolean);
```

check the doc to see what exception will be thrown in such case....